# Mutiple jqx grid table in single page with JqWidgets

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I want to create mutiple jqx grid boxes in single page. can some one please tell me how to do that ? 
Here is the preview page http://jsfiddle.net/NuUjc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do it the same way you create the first grid. Simply create a new div where the grid goes, create necessary data sources, and initialize the grid.

So, in your example, you'd have:

```
<body class='default'>
    <div id='jqxWidget1' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
     </div>
    <br/>Second grid<br/>
    <div id='jqxWidget2' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid2">
        </div>
     </div>
    <br/>Third grid<br/>
    <div id='jqxWidget3' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid3">
        </div>
     </div> </body>
```

then create appropriate data sources and data adapters for your grids: source2, dataAdapter2, etc.

then initialize your grids the same way:

```
    $("#jqxgrid2").jqxGrid(
    {
        width: 670,
        source: dataAdapter2,
    .....
```

Make sure 'jqxgrid2' is replaced with whatever the right id for your grid is (the one you defined in your html snippet)